# Single breaker, split wire that is inaccessible and one wire not working

Tags: wiring

I have an upstairs bedroom and main level entryway light that are on the same breaker.  The entryway light is working, but the bedroom is not.  I have found a wire in the bedroom crawl/attic that isn't hot when the breaker is on, and one wire that is.  I confirmed that the one that is hot is for the entryway light. So there is one wire in attic area that is working correctly and powering the entryway light, and one that is not working that is used for the bedroom.   Is there an issue with cutting the non working wire, capping it and just leaving it in case it comes on, and pig tailing the other side after cutting that feeds the bedroom to the working entryway wire?

Breaker--->Wire from basement--->split two ways to 1.entryway light 2.bedroom

The whole issue started randomly by bedroom power turning off, and light still working.  I am sure they are on same breaker.  All of the 6 switches/outlets in the bedroom are backstabbed.  I changed the two that are used most, and still nothing.  Would one of those outlets going bad be able to cut power only to that area, since the entryway light has always worked properly?  If i could find where the main wire from basement breaker is split, i could fix that, if it's a loose connection.

thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Using a non-contact voltage detector could help you find the broken connection.  Back-stabbed receptacles are certainly a good place to look.

Answer (score 1):

If the bedroom power is being daisy chained through multiple outlets, I would physically check the wiring on each one.  I have encountered problems with backstabbed wiring several times.  Last time I fixed something similar for a friend.  Their power was daisy chained through 4 backstabbed outlets.  The third one in the chain was the problem.  It even tested good with a non-contact voltage reader.  It turned out to be an intermittent arcing connection.  I took out all the backstabs and wired them around the screw terminals.